# Replace a string with another substring using sed in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

For every line except the first line in my file,I want to check if a string already exists . If it does, then do nothing. Otherwise, append the string to the line

For ex - there are foll 3 lines in my file

```
line1 : do_not_modify

line2-string-exists

line3
```

I want to append `-string-exists` to only those lines in the file which does not have that string appended to them(Ignore the first line)

the output should be -

```
line1 : do_not_modify

line2-string-exists

line3-string-exists
```

Please tell me How will I do it using `sed`? Or is it possible to do with `awk`?

Comment: It is possible to solve the problem with `sed` or `awk`. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ cat data
line1 : do_not_modify
line2-string-exists
line3

$ sed '1!{/-string-exists/! s/$/-string-exists/}' data
line1 : do_not_modify
line2-string-exists
line3-string-exists
```

or using `awk`:

```
$ awk '{if(NR!=1 && ! /-string-exists/) {printf "%s%s", $0, "-string-exists\n"} else {print}}' data
line1 : do_not_modify
line2-string-exists
line3-string-exists
```

Comment: Thanks! curly braces were missing from my command. It is working now

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `sed` command:

```
sed -E '/(do_not_modify|-string-exists)$/!s/$/-string-exists/' file

line1 : do_not_modify
line2-string-exists
line3-string-exists
```

Or using `awk`:

```
awk '!/(do_not_modify|-string-exists)$/{$0 = $0 "-string-exists"} 1' file
```

Comment: I don't think "do_not_modify" is actually present in the input file.

Comment: Yes may be OP would have wanted `awk 'NR>1 && !/-string-exists$/{$0 = $0 "-string-exists"} 1' file`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the string doesn't contain any RE metacharacters:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{s="-string-exists"} (NR>1) && ($0!~s"$"){$0=$0 s} 1' file
line1 : do_not_modify
line2-string-exists
line3-string-exists
```